# Can the characteristic of some ring differ from number to number?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

The characteristic of ring is defined as the minimum times multiplicative identity must be added to get additive identity.

<strike>My question is, for every number of ring, can the minimum times a number has to be added to get multiplicative identity differ? (e.g. 2 needs to be added 5 times to get additive identity, while 3 needs 7 times and so forth.)</strike>

And what about the case of commutative ring?

And is there any name for number of times a number has to be multiplied to get additive identity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the ring $\mathbb{Z}_4 = \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ the characteristic is $4$, but $2 + 2 = 0$. You could call this the order of an element in the additive group, perhaps "additive order" would be a good term.

Comment: Indeed, "additive order" of an element is fine.

Answer (score 2):

Given a ring $R$, if 
$$\underbrace{1_R+\cdots+1_R}_{n\text{ times}}=0_R,$$
then for any $a\in R$, we have (by the distributive property) that
$$\underbrace{a+\cdots+a}_{n\text{ times}}=a\cdot\underbrace{\left(1_R+\cdots+1_R\right)}_{n\text{ times}}=a\cdot 0_R=0_R,$$
so whatever the number is for the multiplicative identity, that is an upper bound on the number for any other element.

In the ring $R=(\mathbb{Z}/n_1\mathbb{Z})\times\cdots\times (\mathbb{Z}/n_k\mathbb{Z})$, the element
$$e_i=(\overline{0},\ldots,\underset{\substack{i\text{th}\\\text{place}}}{\overline{1}},\ldots,\overline{0})$$
has the property that
$$\underbrace{e_i+\cdots+e_i}_{n_i\text{ times}}=(\overline{0},\ldots,\overline{0})=0_R,$$
so you can pretty much make a ring with any collection of such numbers you want.

---

Also, I second spin's suggestion that this be referred to as the "additive order" of an element.

Answer (score 1):

Other answers have already clarified the definition of the characteristic of a ring. But I may add one definition that is completely *element-free*, so hopefully this would make things clearer that characteristics do not depend on the *number*.

$\mathbb{Z}$ is initial in the category $\operatorname{Ring}$ (this simply means that for any ring $R$, there is a unique ring homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}\xrightarrow{\phi_R} R$),  thus a ring $R$ uniquely defines a subring of $\mathbb{Z}$, namely, $\operatorname{ker}(\phi_R)$.

This is a subgroup of $(\mathbb{Z},+)$, hence it is generated by some $d\in\mathbb{Z}$, and we can define $d$ to be the characteristic of $R$.

You can easily show that this definition is equivalent to yours, but in this definition we have not mention any *special element*, thus characteristics is a property of the rings themselves.